# React - ShowRainBow.state: must be set to an object or null

Tags: reactjs

I have two components.

1. RainBow.jsx
2. RainBowList.jsx

RainBow.jsx is main component having array and RainBowList.jsx I'm using for showing all rainbow color in li format with map().

I'm getting error in console log as ***ShowRainBow.state: must be set to an object or null***

**My code**

**RainBow.jsx**

```
// Let's import React
import React from "react";

// Import custom component
import RainBowList from "./RainBowList.jsx";

// Let's create component [[ShowRainBow]]
class ShowRainBow extends React.Component{

    // constructor class
    constructor(){
        super();

        // use state with array
        let rainbowColor = this.state = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];

    }   

    render(){       

        return(
            <div className="row">

                <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">   
                    <RainBowList checkColor={this.state.rainbowColor} />
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Let's render ReactDOM
export default ShowRainBow;
```

**RainBowList.jsx**

```
// Let's import react
import React from "react";

// Let's create component [[RainBowList]]
class RainBowList extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                <li> Show rainbow colors </li>
                {
                    this.props.checkColor.map( rainbowcolors =>{
                        return <li rainbowcolors={rainbowcolors} key={rainbowcolors}> {rainbowcolors} </li>
                    })
                }

            </ul>
        );
    }
}

// Let's render ReactDOM
export default RainBowList;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `state` of `ShowRainBow` component as an object instead of an array, like this

```
constructor(){
       super();
       this.state = {rainbowColor: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]};
}
```

Comment: Hi Prakash, just started working on my code and found, in console log I'm getting one more error to my child component it's **Warning: Unknown prop `colorsArrg` on <li> tag. Remove this prop from the element.**. If I'm removing props then it's showing different error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**