# React - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner for React.js and trying to understand concept of props & state with multiple records.

I'm having two components -

1. UserData.jsx
2. UserDataResult.jsx

In UserData.jsx I used this.state for user records. This record I want to show through child component UserDataResult.jsx.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong, so that I'm getting error in console log.

**Error is : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

[image]

**Code:**

** **UserData.jsx** **

```
import React from "react";    
import UserDataResult from "./UserDataResult.jsx";    

class UserData extends React.Component{    

    constructor (props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users : [
                {
                    id : 1,
                    name : "Jack",
                    age : 32,
                    location : "USA",
                    skill : "Drummer",
                },
                {
                    id : 2,
                    name : "Andrew",
                    age : 35,
                    location : "USA",
                    skill : "Guitar player",
                },
            ]
        };

    } 


    render(){    
        return(
            <section>
                <h6> Headline </h6>
                <hr />

                <div>

                    {
                            this.state.users.map( (contact) => {

                                return <UserDataResult contact={contact} />                              

                            } )
                    }

                </div>    
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default UserData;
```

** **UserDataResult.jsx** **

```
import React from "react";

class UserDataResult extends React.Component{
    render(){

        return(  

            <section>    
                <div>

                <p> 
                    {this.props.contact.id}
                    {this.props.contact.name}
                    {this.props.contact.age}
                    {this.props.contact.location}
                    {this.props.contact.skill}
                </p> 
                </div>

            </section>
        );
    }
}
export default UserDataResult;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - ShowRainBow.state: must be set to an object or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119057/react-showrainbow-state-must-be-set-to-an-object-or-null)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your constructor:

You need to include props to allow React to properly pass the props down into the component. I can't recall the exact reason.

```
constructor(props) {                  // you need to include props
    super(props);                     // you need to include it here also
    this.state = {
        users = [
            {
                id : 1,
                name : "Jack",
                age : 32,
                location : "USA",
                skill : "Drummer"
            },
            {
                id : 2,
                name : "Andrew",
                age : 35,
                location : "USA",
                skill : "Guitar player"
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

The above will give you access to `this.state.users` which will be an array.

Then, try this down in your component:

```
<div>
    <UserDataResult checkResult={this.state.users} />
</div>
```

Then, you can update it by pushing into the array.

Try to make something that allows you to call this:

```
const newUsersArray = this.state.users.push({
        id: 3
        name: 'Bob Ross'
        age: 25
        location: 'Cambodia'
        skill: 'Maximum'
    })

this.setState({ users: newUsersArray })
```

You need to treat state as if it is immutable 24/7. Always replace it with an updated value.

React does all kinds of fancy comparisons behind the scenes and helps you optimize performance. Notice how I added the new user to the array and then just reassigned it.

This will prime you for the Redux world, in which we use reducers and directly manipulating state is 100% illegal.

Get in your mind now that doing `this.state.push()` or `state.users.bob = 'ok'` is bad. You want to do what I showed above, and the Bob example would be like:

```
return {
  ...state,
  bob: 'ok'
}
```

What that does is creates a new object and "spreads" the existing state into it, so all of it as it is at that moment, then it simply adds `bob: 'ok'` as a property on that new object and since it occurs after/below, it takes precedence and overwrites the existing key called `bob`.

That's a bit more advanced, but you should know that reducers strive to be `pure functions` and that using React immutably is very important. Do some reading about it.

This stuff has bearing on where, when, and why components `re-render`. It is at the heart of React's blistering performance.

If you call `this.setState()` from inside the **render function**, or a **lifecycle method**, it can go into an infinite loop, because setState triggers a re-rendering of the component, and the re-rendering triggers setState again.

Comment: You're answer is mostly correct, except for a couple of issues. `push` will return the new array length, not a new array. Also, unless using `PureComponent` there is no advantage to treating state as immutable.

Comment: @agm1984, I update my code and after that I'm getting different error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. setState({}) I will do later once I will fix this problem.

Comment: That is something you have to be aware of in React, if you call setState from inside the render function, or a lifecycle method, it can go into an infinite loop, because setState triggers a re-rendering of the component, and the re-rendering triggers setState again :)

Comment: render function is intended to be a pure function that just returns the current state, like displaying the current properties of an object

Comment: Try doing this instead. Figure out how to put a button on the screen, and then give the button an `onClick` property which does that setState. I will get you started: `<button onClick={() => this.setState(...)}>Click Me</button>`

Comment: You can also make a method on your class, which you should start doing because it separates logic out from your render function. Check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. Make another Stack Overflow question if you are having issues with any aspect of that. You will learn a lot as you start experimenting with manipulating `this.state` and creating your own class methods.